# PgAdmin 4 installation on Debian/Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, pgadmin, debian

PgAdmin 4 1.0 has been just released, but on the download page for Linux there is only a link to a yum installer.

Anybody knows if there are plans to create a deb installer? Or if there is already one?

Comment: credativ company has released a pgAdmin4 package for debian: https://packages.credativ.com/public/postgresql/pool/main/p/pgadmin4 - maybe that helps

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are instructions on the pgAdmin site how to install with [`pip`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_(package_manager)):

- https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pip4.php

But there is no official Debian Package (`.deb`), yet. A request for packaging is pending:

- https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=834129

For now, consider the Postgres Apt repository:

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt/FAQ

Comment: It's a pity, but thanks for the confirmation

Comment: Tried installing a host of dependencies but pip install did not work for me (ubuntu 16). I will continue with 3 unless I find clear instructions on an upgrade. Unfortunately 3 column headers disappear frequently and it crashes allot.

Comment: Could install the apache2 version `pgadmin4-apache2` with `deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ stretch-pgdg main` repository